# How can I get my collisions to work with the sides of a platform in my platform?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision, detection

I am currently creating a platform game using python pygame but have gotten stuck with the collisions. I have gotten the bottom and top collisions to work with my character sprite but as of now my character won't stop or bounce off the sides of a platform. when doing collisions, I am using the method `sprite.spritecollide()` which I would like to do in the same way if anyone can help. I have done the collision check correctly but my code for handling the collision I cannot seem to get it done correctly. My code where I do the collision detection is as follows in the main.py in the game update function:

```
import pygame
import random
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from camera import *
from os import path
class Game:
     def __init__(self):
          pygame.init() # initialises pygame
          pygame.mixer.init()
          self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT)) # sets the width and height of the pygame window
          pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
          self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
          self.running = True
          self.font_name = pygame.font.match_font(FONT_NAME)
          self.load_data()

     def load_data(self):
         pass

     def new(self):
         self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
         self.platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
         self.player = Player(self)
         self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
         for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
             p = Platform(*plat)
             self.all_sprites.add(p)
             self.platforms.add(p)
         self.camera = Camera(WIDTH, HEIGHT) # creates the camera with WIDTH and HEIGHT of the screen
         self.run()

     def run(self): # Game Loop - runs the game
         self.playing = True
         while self.playing:
             self.clock.tick(FPS)
             self.events()
             self.update()
             self.draw()

     def update(self): # Game loop - update
         self.all_sprites.update()
         # collision with top of platform
         if self.player.vel.y > 0:
              hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False) # returns a list of platform sprites that hit the player
              if hits:
                   self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
                   self.player.vel.y = 0
         # collision with the bottom of a platform
         if self.player.vel.y < 0:
              hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
              if hits:
                   self.player.top = hits[0].rect.bottom
                   self.player.vel.y = -self.player.vel.y
         # collision with the right side of a platform (moving left), here is the code for the right side of the platform 
         if self.player.acc.x < 0:
              hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
              if hits:
                   self.player.left = hits[0].rect.right
                   self.player.acc.x = 0

         # screen moves with player
         self.camera.update(self.player) # is the camera that tracks players movement

     def events(self): # Game loop - events
         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                  if self.playing:
                      self.playing = False
                  self.running = False
             if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                  if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()

     def draw(self): # Game loop - draw
         self.screen.fill(RED)
         #self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
         for sprite in self.all_sprites:
              self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite)) # loops through the all_sprites group and blit's each sprite onto the screen
         pygame.display.flip()

     def start_screen(self):
         pass

     def game_over_screen(self):
         pass

     def wait_for_key(self):
         pass

     def draw_text(self,text, size, colour, x, y):
         pass

g = Game()
g.start_screen()
while g.running:
     g.new()
     g.game_over_screen()

pygame.quit()
```

I have so far only tried doing collisions for the right side of the platforms, once I've done one side I can replicate for the other side.
P.S. if you need more of my code I will add it to the question if asked to.

**EDIT**

**sprites.py**

```
# will hold the sprite classes
import pygame
from settings import *
import random
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

    def jump(self):
        # jump only if on a platform
        self.rect.x += 1
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        self.rect.x -= 1
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = -20

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC

        # apply friction
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION

        # equations of motion
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        # stop from running of the left side of the screen
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = 0
        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

**camera.py**

```
import pygame
from settings import *
# A camera that keeps track of an offset that will be, how far we want to draw the screen which will include all objects on the screen. We are just shifting the drawing of our screen according to the offset. Camera needs to do two things, apply the offset and then update the movement of where the player is on the screen.
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height): # we will need to tell the camera how wide and high we want it to be
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, height) # is the rectangle we set to keep track of the screen/be the camera
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity): # method to apply the offset to the screen, by shifting the screen according to the movement of the entity within the camera screen
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target): # method to update where the player/target has moved to, updates are done according to last known position of the target
        # as the target moves the camera moves in the opposite direction of the target and stays within the center of the screen
        x = -target.rect.x + int(WIDTH/2)  # left to right
        y = -target.rect.y + int(HEIGHT/2) # up and down

        # limit scrolling to map size, keeps the 'camera' from going over the edges
        x = min(0, x) # left
        y = min(0, y) # top
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y) # bottom
        self.camera = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height) # adjusts the camera's rectangle with the new x and y
```

**settings.py**

```
# Game options/settings
TITLE = 'Platformer'
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
FPS = 60
FONT_NAME = 'arial'
HS_FILE = 'highscore.txt'
SPRITESHEET = 'spritesheet_jumper.png'

# Game colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Starting Platforms:
PLATFORM_LIST = [(0, HEIGHT - 50,  WIDTH, 50), (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 1 / 2, 200, 30), (WIDTH + 150, HEIGHT - 50, WIDTH, 50), (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 4 / 5, 200, 30)]
# player properties
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8
```

Comment: you run the same `spritecollide()` in all `if/else` - so you could run it before `if/else`

Comment: collision's functions don't give information in which side you have collision - so better first update `y`, check collisions, and use `if/else with `vel.y`, next udate `x`, check collisons again and use `if/else with `vel.x`. You should see this method in one of [platform examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38_4) on page [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test your code but usually problem is that `spritecollide` doesn't inform if you collide on `x` or `y` or both.

When you move `x` and `y` at once and check collision then you don't know if you collided on `x` or `y` or both. If you collided only on `y` and you will check `vel.x` and move player then you get wrong result. The same if you collided only on `x` and you will check `vel.y` and move player then you get also wrong result.

You have to do it separatelly:

- first move only `x`, check collisions and check only `vel.x`,
- next move only `y`, check collisions again and check only `vel.y`,

Something like this:

```
 def update(self):
     #self.all_sprites.update()

     # collision with top and bottom of platform

     # update only y

     self.player.pos.y += self.player.vel.y + 0.5 * self.player.acc.y
     
     hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
     
     if hits:
         if self.player.vel.y > 0:
             self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
             self.player.vel.y = 0
    
         elif self.player.vel.y < 0:
             self.player.top = hits[0].rect.bottom
             self.player.vel.y = -self.player.vel.y

     # collision with left and right of platform

     # update only x

     self.player.pos.x += self.player.vel.x + 0.5 * self.player.acc.x
     
     hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)

     if hits:
         if self.player.acc.x < 0:
             self.player.left = hits[0].rect.right
             self.player.acc.x = 0
             
         elif self.player.acc.x > 0:
             self.player.right = hits[0].rect.left
             self.player.acc.x = 0
```

---

You should see working example in [platform examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38_4) on page  [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php)

---

**EDIT:**

Full code

**main.py**

```
#import random
#from os import path
import pygame

from settings import *
from sprites import *
from camera import *

class Game:
    
    def __init__(self):
        # initialises pygame
        pygame.init()
        #pygame.mixer.init()  # `pygame.init()` should aready runs `pygame.mixer.init()`
          
        # sets the width and height of the pygame window
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)

        self.font_name = pygame.font.match_font(FONT_NAME)
        self.load_data()
        
        # main loop elements
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.running = True

    def load_data(self):
        pass

    def new(self):
        """Run game"""
        
        self.reset()
        self.run()
        
    def reset(self):
        """Reset data"""
        
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
         
        for plat in PLATFORM_LIST:
            p = Platform(*plat)
            self.all_sprites.add(p)
            self.platforms.add(p)

        # creates the camera with WIDTH and HEIGHT of the screen
        self.camera = Camera(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    def run(self):
        """Game Loop - runs the game"""
        
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def update(self):
        """Game loop - update"""
        
        self.all_sprites.update()
        # screen moves with player
        self.camera.update(self.player) # is the camera that tracks players movement

    def events(self):
        """Game loop - events"""
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                    self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # reset game but not exit 
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    if self.playing:
                        self.playing = False
                    
            # send event(s) to sprite(s) 
            self.player.events(event)
             
    def draw(self):
        """Game loop - draw"""

        self.screen.fill(RED)
        
        # loops through the all_sprites group and blit's each sprite onto the screen
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            sprite.draw(self.screen, self.camera)
        
        pygame.display.flip()

    def start_screen(self):
        pass

    def game_over_screen(self):
        pass

    def wait_for_key(self):
        pass

    def draw_text(self,text, size, colour, x, y):
        pass

# --- main ---

g = Game()

g.start_screen()

while g.running:
     g.new()
     g.game_over_screen()

#g.exit_screen()

pygame.quit()
```

**sprites.py**

```
# will hold the sprite classes
import random
import pygame
from settings import *

vec = pygame.math.Vector2


class BaseSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Base class with functions for all sprites"""

    def draw(self, screen, camera):
        screen.blit(self.image, camera.apply(self))
    
    
class Player(BaseSprite):
    
    def __init__(self, game):
        #pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        
        self.game = game
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)

        self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        self.on_ground = True
        
    def jump(self):
        if self.on_ground:
            self.vel.y = -20
            self.on_ground = False

    def events(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
              self.jump()
        
    def update(self):

        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC

        # apply friction
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * PLAYER_FRICTION

        # equations of motion
        self.vel += self.acc

        # --- horizontal collision ---
        
        self.pos.x += self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc.x
        self.rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        
        # stop from running of the left side of the screen
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
            self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
            
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        
        if hits:
            if self.vel.x > 0:
                self.rect.right = hits[0].rect.left
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                self.vel.x = 0
            elif self.vel.x < 0:
                self.rect.left = hits[0].rect.right
                self.pos.x = self.rect.centerx
                self.vel.x = 0

        # --- vertical collision ---

        self.pos.y += self.vel.y + 0.5 * self.acc.y
        self.rect.centery = self.pos.y

        # game over when left screen 
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.game.playing = False

        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        
        if hits:
            if self.vel.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = hits[0].rect.top
                self.pos.y = self.rect.centery
                self.vel.y = 0
                self.on_ground = True
            elif self.vel.y < 0:
                self.rect.top = hits[0].rect.bottom
                self.pos.y = self.rect.centery
                self.vel.y = 0


class Platform(BaseSprite):
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        #pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #self.rect.x = x
        #self.rect.y = y
        
        # shorter
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
```

**camera.py**

without changes

**settings.py**

I added few platforms

```
# Game options/settings
TITLE = 'Platformer'
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 500
FPS = 60
FONT_NAME = 'arial'
HS_FILE = 'highscore.txt'
SPRITESHEET = 'spritesheet_jumper.png'

# Game colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Starting Platforms:
PLATFORM_LIST = [
    # grounds
    (0, HEIGHT - 50,  WIDTH, 50, GREEN),
    (WIDTH + 150, HEIGHT - 50, WIDTH, 50, GREEN),
    # platforms
    (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 1 / 2, 200, 30, YELLOW),
    (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT * 4 / 5, 200, 30, YELLOW),
    # walls
    (WIDTH - 30, HEIGHT - 250, 30, 200, WHITE),
    (WIDTH + 150, HEIGHT - 250, 30, 200, WHITE),
]

# player properties
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_FRICTION = -0.12
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.8
```

I was thinging to moves some code to class `Screen` and then I would use this class to create `GameScreen`, `StartScreen`, `GameOverScreen`, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the help thank you, so what you are sayiing is that I need to update x and y separately?... I'm using vectors in my update method for my player class can it still work as you said?... I am quite new to pygame so please forgive my lacking knowledge (I will include my sprites module in my question)

Comment: in update you will have to only change `vel` and `acc` but not `pos` nor `rect`. You will need change code `pos` and `rect` when you check collision. First change only `self.pos.x` and `self.rect.x` and check collision only left-right, next change only `self.pos.y` and `self.rect.y` and check collision only up-down.

Comment: so I need to update methods one to only update in the x direction and one to update in the y direction?

Comment: yes, first you have to move only in x direction and check collision - and if you get hit then you will know that it was coliision in x direction, not y direction. Next you move in y direction and check collision again - and if you get hit then you will know that it was collision in y direction, not in x direction. When you move in both direction at once and check collision then you can't know if it was collision only in x direction, or only in y direction or in both directions.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I still can't seem to get it working. Is it ok if you give me a start on how it is done?

Comment: I've done something like:                                                   
```def update_in_x(self):
        self.pos.x += 1
        self.rect.x += 1
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.game.platforms, False)
        self.pos.x -= 1
        self.rect.x -= 1
        if hits:
            return True ```

Comment: I already gave you function - you may update position directly in in `update()` - and use real values `self.vel.x + 0.5 * self.acc` - not fake value `+1`. And don't move it back - don't use `-1`

Comment: I changed code and now I change player position directly in `update()` without `update_in_x()` and `update_in_y()`

Comment: I got your code and run it and made changes - now in answer you have full running code with all my changes - not only collisions but also few other changes.

Comment: thank you very much I appreciate the help you've gone above and beyond